# AngularJS: Programmatically change route without changing URL till resolver is resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

When I change the route with `$location.path(myPath)` with a resolver to get some data, the route in the URL changes, and the active route also changes. However, the ng-view doesn't change to the new route till it's resolved.

This has an undesired effect of flickering the screen, or showing multiple parts of the web app at the same time while waiting for the route to resolve.

Can I change the route in such a way that the route in the URL does not change till the resolver resolves?

**AngularJS 1.5**

Comment: which router are you using?

Comment: @charlietfl ngRoute https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: if early in project try ui-router...switching isn't much work and there are lots of far more robust advantages

Comment: @charlietfl Early-ish. I have a pretty robust chunk of routing, and routing-related logic. Does it have backwards compatibility with already setup logic for $routeChangeStart, $routeChangeComplete, $locationChangeStart...etc or will those need to be rewritten?

Comment: should be the same as i remember...been quite a while since i used ngRoute since the features in ui-router are a whole lot more robust. The event names however are almost identical with exception of changing `'$route'` to `'$state'`

Comment: Does using $routeProvider.when.reloadOnSearch get what you want?